# do you skip the a at the beginning of a word after a previous word ends in a consonant?

Tags: pronunciation

For example:

All American => All Merican

Automated analysis => Automated nalysis

You get the idea?

Comment: Nope, I dont think so, that doesnt sound right.

Comment: What leads you to think that you should do so?

Comment: The Americans pronouncing these word combinations

Comment: You might if you're exceptionally, *exceptionally* Southern. Haha!

Comment: America is rather large. Whence came these 'mericans?

Comment: I live in California so this is pretty much where I heard it. May be the "a" is glided over very quickly so it seems as if they are not really pronouncing it.

Comment: Keeto - "Merica" is a trope. I'm American, and I say *America*. It's possible you don't hear the *a*.

Comment: Must just be a local custom.

Comment: So, what exactly is the question here? Going by your comments, it's rhetorical at best, and peeving at worst. Please clarify what it is you want us to tell you that you don't already know.

Comment: @RegDwigнt The question is in the title

Comment: Yes, and going by your comments, it's rhetorical at best, and peeving at worst. Please clarify what it is you want us to tell you that you don't already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons why this is likely to happen in common spoken (aka lazy) English:

1) There are few examples of a "glottal stop" in English, as there are in say Arabic, and so Americans, tend to slam these sounds together.  Consider "lexical analysis" which requires no glottal stop. It this case you are more likely to hear, "lexica lanalysis", but the "a" sound is very much present.

2) It is more likely to happen when the emphasis in the second word is not on the first syllable, as in AMERican and aNALysis. Consider "American Aardvark" or "American Apple". Again, you are more likely to hear, "America Napple".

But in proper spoken English, these are not skipped.